# Animate mobile navigation and background-color without lag on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

[image: Gif of dropdown lag]

As can be seen in the running code; the navbar, on page scroll, is fixed at the top, changes its logo to a blue one and also has a white background.
On mobile, the menu should either slide down or appear smoothly without any lag on top of the content on mobile screens nicely.

I have been struggling to seamlessly animate the mobile menu slide-down and background-color smoothly without any lag on mobile devices. I have tried `max-height` to set the height of the navbar. Everything I have tried has resulted in lag on all mobile devices I have tested it with.

Honestly speaking, I have been unable to achieve that for two days. I have exhausted all methods and I am now frustrated. I don't know why it runs smoothly on desktops but heavily lags on mobile devices.

What can I do?

```js
const logo = document.getElementById("pageLogo");
const pageBurgerIcon = document.getElementById("pageBurgerIcon");
const pageCloseMenu = document.getElementById("pageCloseMenu");
const pageMainNav = document.getElementById("pageMainNav");
const fixedNavbar = document.querySelector(".page__navigation");


document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
    fixedNavbar.classList.add('scrolled');
    pageBurgerIcon.classList.add("active");
    logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
    
  } else {
    fixedNavbar.classList.remove('scrolled');
    pageBurgerIcon.classList.remove("active");

    if (!pageMainNav.classList.contains("opened")) {
      if (logo.classList.contains("logo-white")) {
        logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo_qtqmny.svg";
      } else {
        logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
      }
    }
  }
})

pageBurgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pageMainNav.classList.add("opened");
  pageBurgerIcon.classList.remove("show");
  pageCloseMenu.classList.add("show");
  logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
})


pageCloseMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pageMainNav.classList.remove("opened");
  pageBurgerIcon.classList.add("show");
  pageCloseMenu.classList.remove("show");
  document.body.style.overflow = "";

  if (logo.classList.contains("logo-white")) {
    if(!fixedNavbar.classList.contains("scrolled")) {
      logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo_qtqmny.svg";
    } else {
      logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
    }
  } else {
    logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
  }
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #12213c;
}


/* Page container to make it centered across all screens */
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}


/* Header Styles */
.page__header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

/* Navbar Container Styles */
.page__navigation {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000 !important;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

/* Navbar Styles*/

.page__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem 0 5rem 0;
}

/* Logo */
.page__logo {
  padding-left: 6rem;
}
.page__logo-img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

/* Navbar menu list */
.page__menu {
  padding-right: 6rem;
}
.page__menu-icon {
  display: none;
  fill: #fff;
}
.page__menu-icon.blue {
  fill: #0066a1;
}
.page__menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  color: #0066a1;
}
.page__menu a.active {
  color: #3ab449 !important;
}
.page__menu a:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding-left: 4rem;
}


/* Navigation Container on scroll settings */
.page__navigation.scrolled {
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

/* On scroll styling for the navbar which is a direct child of the navigation container */
.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav {
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
}

.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav .page__menu-icon {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav .page__menu a {
  color: #0066a1;
}
.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav .page__menu a.active {
  color: #3ab449;
}



/* Page content section */
.page__intro p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Page content padding for space */
.page-top-padding {
  padding: 20rem 6rem 11.5rem 6rem;
}


/* Media query for mobile devices with a screen of less than or equal to 600px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.9rem;
  }

  /* Navbar Container */
  .page__navigation {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  /* Navbar Styles */
  .page__nav {
    position: fixed !important;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    z-index: 10000;
  }

  /* Navbar when opened */
  .page__nav.opened {
    height: 80%;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-radius: 0 0 32px 32px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  }

  /* Navbar menu list/links styles */
  .page__nav.opened .page__menu a {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
  }



  /* Navbar logo */
  .page__logo {
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 102.4px;
    top: -2.5rem;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* Navbar menu */
  .page__menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 70px 20px 20px 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .page__menu a {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #12213c !important;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .page__menu a:not(:first-of-type) {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .page__menu-icon {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.show {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.white {
    fill: #fff;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.dark {
    fill: #12213c;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.active {
    fill: #00aeef !important;
  }


  /* Navbar content padding */

  .page-top-padding {
    padding: 10rem 2rem 11.5rem 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Container -->
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <!-- Page Header ? Top Section-->
    <header class="page__header page__header-home">
      <!-- Navbar Container -->
      <div class="page__navigation">

        <!-- Navbar Container -->
        <nav class="page__nav" id="pageMainNav">
          <svg width="24" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="page__menu-icon show white" id="pageBurgerIcon">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0H12V2.85715H0V0ZM24 8.5713V11.4285H0V8.5713H24ZM18 17.1429H0V20.0001H18V17.1429Z"/>
          </svg>
          <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="page__menu-icon" id="pageCloseMenu">
            <path d="M11.9997 10L20 18.0003L18.0003 20L10 11.9997L1.99966 20L0 18.0003L8.00034 10L0 1.99966L1.99966 0L10 8.00034L18.0003 0L20 1.99966L11.9997 10Z" fill="#00AEEF"/>
          </svg>
            
          <div class="page__logo">
            <a href="/">
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo_qtqmny.svg" alt="page Logo" class="page__logo-img logo-white" id="pageLogo">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="page__menu home">
            <a href="">Menu 1</a>
            <a href="">Menu 2</a>
            <a href="">Menu 3</a>
            <a href="">Menu 4</a>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Intro/Top Section -->
      <section class="page__intro page-top-padding">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      </section>
    </header>

  </div>
```

Comment: Very beautiful indeed!

Comment: @Aniox Thank you. Only that it won't make much of a difference if I can't  get it to work without lag on mobile devices. Do you have any idea what I can add or remove or modify to that code to make it run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `padding` and `height` you set on the `.scroll` classes are making it jolt.

From these sections:

```
/* Navigation Container on scroll settings */
.page__navigation.scrolled {
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

/* On scroll styling for the navbar which is a direct child of the navigation container */
.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav {
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
}

.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav .page__menu-icon {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

---

Is this how you want it?

```js
const logo = document.getElementById("pageLogo");
const pageBurgerIcon = document.getElementById("pageBurgerIcon");
const pageCloseMenu = document.getElementById("pageCloseMenu");
const pageMainNav = document.getElementById("pageMainNav");
const fixedNavbar = document.querySelector(".page__navigation");


document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
    fixedNavbar.classList.add('scrolled');
    pageBurgerIcon.classList.add("active");
    logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";

  } else {
    fixedNavbar.classList.remove('scrolled');
    pageBurgerIcon.classList.remove("active");

    if (!pageMainNav.classList.contains("opened")) {
      if (logo.classList.contains("logo-white")) {
        logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo_qtqmny.svg";
      } else {
        logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
      }
    }
  }
})

pageBurgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pageMainNav.classList.add("opened");
  pageBurgerIcon.classList.remove("show");
  pageCloseMenu.classList.add("show");
  logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
})


pageCloseMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pageMainNav.classList.remove("opened");
  pageBurgerIcon.classList.add("show");
  pageCloseMenu.classList.remove("show");
  document.body.style.overflow = "";

  if (logo.classList.contains("logo-white")) {
    if (!fixedNavbar.classList.contains("scrolled")) {
      logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo_qtqmny.svg";
    } else {
      logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
    }
  } else {
    logo.src = "https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo-other_apqmct.svg";
  }
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #12213c;
}


/* Page coontainer to make it centered across all screens */
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}


/* Header Styles */
.page__header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

/* Navbar Container Styles */
.page__navigation {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

/* Navbar Styles*/

.page__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem 0 5rem 0;
}

/* Logo */
.page__logo {
  padding-left: 6rem;
}
.page__logo-img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

/* Navbar menu list */
.page__menu {
  padding-right: 6rem;
}
.page__menu-icon {
  display: none;
  fill: #fff;
}
.page__menu-icon.blue {
  fill: #0066a1;
}
.page__menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  color: #0066a1;
}
.page__menu a.active {
  color: #3ab449 !important;
}
.page__menu a:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding-left: 4rem;
}


/* Naviagtion Container on scroll settings */
.page__navigation.scrolled {
  background: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

/* On scroll styling for the navbar which is a direct child of the navigation container */
.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav .page__menu a {
  color: #0066a1;
}
.page__navigation.scrolled > nav.page__nav .page__menu a.active {
  color: #3ab449;
}



/* Page content section */
.page__intro p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Page content padding for space */
.page-top-padding {
  padding: 20rem 6rem 11.5rem 6rem;
}


/* Media query for mobile devices with a screen of less than or equal to 600px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.9rem;
  }

  /* Navbar Container */
  .page__navigation {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  /* Navbar Styles */
  .page__nav {
    position: fixed !important;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    z-index: 10000;
  }

  /* Navbar when opened */
  .page__nav.opened {
    height: 80%;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-radius: 0 0 32px 32px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  }

  /* Navbar menu list/links styles */
  .page__nav.opened .page__menu a {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
  }



  /* Navbar logo */
  .page__logo {
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 102.4px;
    top: -2.5rem;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* Navbar menu */
  .page__menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 70px 20px 20px 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .page__menu a {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #12213c !important;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .page__menu a:not(:first-of-type) {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .page__menu-icon {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.show {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.white {
    fill: #fff;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.dark {
    fill: #12213c;
  }
  .page__menu-icon.active {
    fill: #00aeef !important;
  }


  /* Navbar content padding */

  .page-top-padding {
    padding: 10rem 2rem 11.5rem 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Container -->
<div class="container" id="container">
  <!-- Page Header ? Top Section-->
  <header class="page__header page__header-home">
    <!-- Navbar Container -->
    <div class="page__navigation">

      <!-- Navbar Container -->
      <nav class="page__nav" id="pageMainNav">
        <svg width="24" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="page__menu-icon show white" id="pageBurgerIcon">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0H12V2.85715H0V0ZM24 8.5713V11.4285H0V8.5713H24ZM18 17.1429H0V20.0001H18V17.1429Z"/>
          </svg>
        <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="page__menu-icon" id="pageCloseMenu">
            <path d="M11.9997 10L20 18.0003L18.0003 20L10 11.9997L1.99966 20L0 18.0003L8.00034 10L0 1.99966L1.99966 0L10 8.00034L18.0003 0L20 1.99966L11.9997 10Z" fill="#00AEEF"/>
          </svg>

        <div class="page__logo">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/iolamide/image/upload/v1600625296/logo_qtqmny.svg" alt="page Logo" class="page__logo-img logo-white" id="pageLogo">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="page__menu home">
          <a href="">Menu 1</a>
          <a href="">Menu 2</a>
          <a href="">Menu 3</a>
          <a href="">Menu 4</a>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Intro/Top Section -->
    <section class="page__intro page-top-padding">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eius, porro quaerat repellat enim consequuntur architecto doloribus laborum culpa quam nulla.</p>
    </section>
  </header>

</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the fix of the jolting problem. However, that is not what I am looking for. If you check this out on a low or mid end android device, the animation lags when the burger icon is clicked for the menu to show. Removing the padding fixed the jolting problem but not the main problem I want solved

Comment: Could you make a GIF of the problem? Don't know what to suggest without being able to see what you mean

Comment: I have added the gif to the question. Check it out. I appreciate that suggestion

Comment: I just tried fixing it on my android but couldn't find any way around it. I think it might just be the processing power of the phone

Comment: Yes. That's what I think as well. Did it run well on your android? It runs well on my friend's iPhone

Comment: It was laggy on my phone. I had a similar issue where it worked fine on someone else's phone but laggy on mine

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it tbh